# Run function multiple times with different inputs and save values

Tags: python

I am trying to get a DataFrame for each "ticker" in list `l` by running it through the same function.

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import csv

def price(ticker):
    company = yf.Ticker(ticker)
    price = company.history(period='max')
    price_df = pd.DataFrame(price)
    price_df.to_csv('test2.csv', index=False)

l = ["AAPL", "KO"]
for ticker in l:
    price(ticker)
```

How can I make a different DataFrame for each entry in `l` while using the same function?

Comment: You can take in the csv file as an input. Alternatively, you can append to the csv file.

Comment: What is the expected output of `price(ticker)`? A dataframe?

Comment: @gnahum how can I append to the csv file? If I just append it, the csv file will still only yield the last entry in the list.

Comment: @asikorski the output would be a few thousand rows of data with stock price information, I am trying to create a unique DataFrame of each entry in the list through the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import csv

def price(ticker):
    company = yf.Ticker(ticker)
    price = company.history(period='max')
    price_df = pd.DataFrame(price)
    return price_df

l = ["AAPL", "KO"]
for ticker in l:
    df = price(ticker)  # do something with each dataframe
```

I am not sure if I understood your question correctly, but it sounds just like returning the created dataframe.